# Ubuntu Stopped Booting Even USB

Tags: boot, dual-boot, usb

I dual boot and use Windows 10 everyday. I boot into Ubuntu 16.04 about once a month. I use GRUB2, nothing fancy.

Yesterday I tried to boot into Ubuntu and it just wouldn't. It froze on the Ubuntu loading screen. My keyboard was locked and the only thing I could do was hold down the power button to shutdown the PC. I tried to boot into recovery mode and experienced the same issue.

Okay, so I think, "Windows 10 update must have messed something up." So I d/l 18.04 beta, so I use Rufus to create a USB bootable drive. I select install Ubuntu and it locks up again. I reboot, hit try Ubuntu and it locks again.

I try Unetbootin to create a new USB image, thinking perhaps it's something there and come up with the same issue.

I can not boot into Ubuntu no matter what I try. I do not know how to get a log file, but from what I'm seeing, it's just locked at the loading screen.

I've searched this topic, but every solution I can find says to boot to a USB stick, but that has the same issue as the installed OS. I have not changed hardware and have ran Windows diagnostics but found no issues. What can I do?

Comment: When you try to boot into recovery mode, EXACTLY how far do you get?

Comment: Responding to this via cell phone as my PC no longer boots to anything. Ubuntu was saying.... Crap it won't let me put a /n. It was saying ata10.00 10B8B BadCRC. I unplugged ata10 and it persisted. So I unplugged everything except for my DVD drive that I'm trying to boot from. It's plugged into my 3rd sata slot. However Ubuntu is now giving ata8.00 the same error message as ata10 had

Comment: Windows was starting to have strange issues as well so I decided to reinstall it. It booted and ran for a little while, but after the 3rd restart windows said it was corrupt and unable to fix the problem. I'm pretty sure my controller is bad and I need a new mb, but I'm going to find another power supply and try that first